# Файлы в dev/fd и процессы

Tags: c, unix

Читаю книгу Юникс Стивенса. Пишет следующее: открытие файла dev/fd/n эквивалентно созданию ДУБЛИКАТА дескриптора с номером n.
Я открыл dev/fd и вижу что имеется много разных файлов, имя которых представлено в виде номера. 
Возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Дескрипторы чьих процессов находятся в /dev/fd/?
2. Если я создам процесс (автоматом будут с процессом ассоциированы дескрипторы 0,1,2) где будут находиться эти файлы, представляющие дескрипторы(я думаю что в dev/fd)?Но  в dev/fd уже есть файлы с такими именами
3. Если я запускаю процесс и получаю дубликат fd , например файла dev/fd/0. Это что вообще такое получиться?)) По идее у меня мой и ещё какой то процесс будут иметь один STDIN...так ли это?

Comment: `/dev/fd` — это мягкая ссылка на `/proc/self/fd`, а `/proc/self` — мягкая ссылка на «персональный» каталог самого процесса, запрашивающего эту информацию. т.е., для каждого процесса содержимое `/dev/fd` (а точнее, `/proc/номер-процесса/fd`) — уникально.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, стоит оговориться, что так реализовано это только в linux.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, детали, конечно, отличаются, а суть («для каждого процесса содержимое `/dev/fd` — уникально») везде одинакова. // к слову: в solaris-е `/dev/fd` — виртуальная файловая система, во freebsd — `/dev` (как и в gnu/linux, собственно)